# English Football Club ownership

Tags: corporate-law, sport

I have been wondering if club fans have the power to sanction the compulsory sale of the club by an owner whom they perceive as frustrating their club's future. In any case, the money comes from these people (fans) through club products, match tickets etc
For example a substantial number of Arsenal fans perceive Kroenke's ownership as sabotaging the supposed glory of the club in that he does not invest in the club to make it competitive. Same for Manchester United fans with the Glazer family.

Comment: "the money comes from these people (fans) through club products, match tickets etc": similarly, my expenditures contribute to the revenue of tech giants and the corner grocer alike.  But the only way I can obtain an ownership interest in any of those companies is by buying shares on the stock market (if the company is public) or by negotiating a private investment (in the case of the corner grocer and other privately held companies).  If a company that makes a product I like decides to change the product so I don't like it anymore, I don't have much recourse. This happens frequently, in fact.

Comment: I feel like these corporations are increasingly being viewed with more 'public'' perspective. There should be a way fans can make their voices heard and considered in a more impactful manner. While I don't doubt these clubs consider their fans, fans should be able to compel substantial decisions like spending during transfer window, managers etc

Comment: Well that may be true from an ethical perspective, and many clubs will want to take that into account as a business decision, but that doesn't change the fact that it *is* a business decision.  From the legal perspective, if the fans want control over business decisions, they can pool their resources and make an offer for an ownership stake.

Answer (score 5):

Do fans legally have any ownership rights? Generally, no. It can be done if an agreement of the team is put into place when the team is founded or if the current owner agrees to it (which can then be binding on whomever the team is sold/transferred to).

There are some leagues, such as the Bundesliga (Thank you Nij, for the correction; Sports in general are not my thing) where the clubs must be owned by fans, at least 51%. So it can be done, but cannot be forced on an owner against their will, unless such a covenant is agreed to before they take possession of the club. It can be required for a given club to join/participate in a given league.

Legally, supporting a club via buying club merch and match tickets give an ownership interest in the items bought, not in the club/team itself.

Comment: You're thinking of Bundesliga, where clubs only receive a license to compete if they hold a strict majority of their own voting rights (i.e. the club members and fans own most of the club).

Comment: @Nij: Thank you; as I said, sports are not usually my thing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is clear from your response that there's a way to compel all clubs to comply with such a provision accommodating fans, like in Bundesliga. I hope English football steers that path

Comment: The Premier League exists precisely because the FA tried to exert such controls. English football in general has a long history of splitting and diverging and refusing to compromise regardless of how sensible the change or minor the restriction. It won't happen.

Comment: @user18858: as Nij says, you are taking the wrong thing away from my answer. There is no way to compel an owner to give up ownership (barring something like government seizure); the fans can buy the club, in whole or in part, at the price the owner desires. Leagues may require such a percentage of fan ownership in order for teams to participate, but can't force teams to remain in their leagues.

Answer (score 1):

### The owner owns the club

And owners can do whatever lawful thing they like with their stuff - that’s pretty much the definition of ownership.

In the modern world, most sporting “clubs”, even junior clubs for children, are owned by a corporation (not necessarily a company though) under the local law. Details vary but the decisions and actions of the club are carried out by the board (of directors) and the employees or volunteers under the board’s direction. The role of the shareholders (other names are used depending on the exact corporate structure) it to appoint or elect the board and vote on resolutions at general meetings. The powers (and limitations on) the board are set by local law and the rules of the organisation which are established with the organisation and can usually be changed by special resolution.

So in summary:

- Employees or volunteers carry out the day-to-day operations
- Senior employees (executives) manage the day-to-day operations
- Directors monitor operations and set long-term goals and strategy for the benefit of all shareholders
- Shareholders appoint the directors

Shareholders do not control the operations of a club except through influence and their ability to appoint and dismiss directors.

### So where do "members" fit in?

First, be aware that shareholders can be called members but that's not who you are talking about.

Members, in the context that you use it, means "customers". They have no control over operations and their only influence is the same as the customers of any other business - to stop being customers or to make their displeasure felt through the media or protest or email etc. The owner of the business can choose to listen to them or ignore them - after all, it's their club and they can do with it what they like.

Comment: like the company law perspective. I'll now view myself as a customer who can take or piss off.